# Could precognition explain the choreographed look of lightsaber duels?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, lightsaber

If you watch the lightsaber fights in the Prequel Trilogy, you'll see a lot of flips and twirls and duelists aiming for each other's lightsabers. Overall, a bunch of flair you would deem unnecessary and even detrimental in a real sword fight. But I'm wondering if Battle Precognition could explain why force users fight like this, as well as why lightsaber duels last so much longer than real sword fights: a duelist can see their opponent's attack coming and preemptively move their own body/lightsaber to dodge or block it. This might also be why they sometimes seem to move in sync.

Comment: This sounds like fun headcanon, but what kind of answer are you looking for? Check the [tour] if you haven't already, to understand how this site is different from a normal discussion forum.

Comment: What an interesting idea! Definitely worth discussing, but it's not really a question, so not here.

Comment: I might answer the question from the subject here as "*more than likely, yes.*" The novel, "***Thrawn: Alliances***" goes into some detail about Anakin's "double vision" (precognition) as he deflects blaster bolts and such. I would imagine that, if the two combatants share the same ability to see the others' moves before they happen, such fights would come down to a matter of the eventual victor glimpsing an upcoming mistake to be made by the eventual loser, whether due to exhaustion, lack of skill, or over-extension in some way.